# Homotopy (co)limit (co)cones

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathscr{M}$ be a model category and let $\mathscr{I}$ be a small category. Consider any homotopy colimit functor $\text{hcolim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}\colon\mathscr{M}^{\mathscr{I}}\longrightarrow \mathscr{M}$ of shape $\mathscr{I}$ on $\mathscr{M}$. Here I adopt the notion of homotopy colimit considered in [Homotopy Limit Functors on Model Categories and Homotopical Categories](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-113) where a homotopy colimit is defined as a left approximation of the colimit functor.

Given a functor $X\colon\mathscr{I}\longrightarrow \mathscr{M}$, let me call a cocone $X\rightarrow P$ from $X$ (that is, a natural transformation $X\rightarrow cP$, where $P\in\mathscr{M}$ and $c$ is the constant functor $\mathscr{M}\longrightarrow \mathscr{M}^{\mathscr{I}}$) a *homotopy colimit cocone* if the canonical composite map
$$
\text{hcolim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}X\rightarrow \text{colim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}X\rightarrow P
$$ 
is a weak equivalence. Note that, given another homotopy colimit functor $\textbf{hcolim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}$ of shape $\mathscr{I}$ over $\mathscr{M}$, the map $\text{hcolim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}X\rightarrow P$ is a weak equivalence if and only if $\textbf{hcolim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}X\rightarrow P$ is a weak equivalence because $\text{hcolim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}$ and $\textbf{hcolim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}$ are naturally weakly equivalent as functors over the colimit functor $\text{colim}_{\mathscr{M}}^{\mathscr{I}}$.

Let me now say that a functor $F\colon \mathscr{M}\longrightarrow \mathscr{N}$ between model categories *preserves homotopy colimit cocones* if, for every $X\in\mathscr{M}^{\mathscr{I}}$ (for a small category $\mathscr{I}$) and every homotopy colimit cocone $X\rightarrow P$ from $X$, $F\circ X\rightarrow FP$ is a homotopy colimit cocone from $F\circ X$.

Of course, we can dually define the concepts of *homotopy limit cones* and of *preserving homotopy limit cones*.

I would like to know if these notions are somehow well understood and/or useful. I am in particular interested in the following questions which I can not answer:

1) Let $F\colon \mathscr{M}\longrightarrow \mathscr{N}$ be a left Quillen functor and let $Q\colon\mathscr{M}\longrightarrow \mathscr{M}$ be a cofibrant replacement functor on $\mathscr{M}$. Does $F\circ Q$ preserve homotopy colimit cocones (and dually for a right Quillen functor)?

2) If $F\colon \mathscr{M}\longrightarrow \mathscr{N}$ is a left Quillen functor which is part of a Quillen equivalence and $Q$ is a cofibrant replacement functor on $\mathscr{M}$, does $F\circ Q$ preserve homotopy limit cones (and dually for a right Quillen functor)?

Comment: I don't think your definition of homotopy colimit cocone is correct. For instance, consider any diagram in $\mathbf{sSet}$ whose homotopy colimit is non-contractible but whose strict colimit is a point.

Comment: Dear @ZhenLin, I guess I can see what you would like to suggest. However, I do not fully understand what you mean when you say that the definition is not "correct". Maybe I should have said it before, but I used the terminology "homotopy colimit cocone" just because I had to find a way to call a cocone having that property. However, I am not claiming that my definition should coincide with another one that perhaps is already conventional (I do not know if this is the case).[...]

Comment: [...] In giving that definition I was motivated by the usual notion of homotopy pushout and homotopy pullback squares, where, for the homotopy pullback case, say, one requires to a commutative square to be such that the canonical map from the top left corner to the homotopy limit of the cospan consisting of the remaining three vertices is a weak equivalence. To me, it seems like the only meaningful "canonical map" is the one factoring through the ordinary limit of that cospan so that the notion of homotopy pullback seemed to be a particular instance of my notion of homotopy limit cone...

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't think he's asserting that homotopy colimit cocones exist for all diagrams.

Comment: Well, the only condition I can think of that guarantees that this notion of homotopy colimit cocone is meaningful is that the canonical comparison $\mathrm{hocolim} \to \mathrm{colim}$ is itself a weak equivalence. This happens, of course, but I think it also trivialises the question.

Comment: @TylerLawson Indeed, I am not.

Comment: @ZhenLin I would still be interested in a complete answer (or in a reference to an answer) to questions (1) and (2) just for homotopy colimit or limit diagrams as well, i.e. for those diagrams $X\colon\mathscr{I}\rightarrow\mathscr{M}$ such that $\text{hcolim}X\rightarrow \text{colim}X$ or $\text{lim}X\rightarrow \text{hlim}X$ is a weak equivalence.

Comment: @ZhenLin This probably sounds silly to you, but I can not exactly understand how that fact should imply preservation of homotopy colimits as in (1) (and this is precisely the source of my questions). I know that, when $F$ is a left Quillen functor, $FQ\text{hcolim}$ and $\text{hcolim} FQ$ are (canonically) naturally weakly equivalent as functors over $F\text{colim}\cong\text{colim} F$, for any cofibrant replacement functor Q, but I do not see how to deduce from this that, if $X\colon\mathscr{I}\rightarrow\mathscr{M}$ is a hcolim diagram,[...]

Comment: [...] then $\text{hcolim}FQX\rightarrow \text colim FQX$ is a weak equivalence.

Comment: If you add the hypothesis that all objects in $\mathcal{M}$ are cofibrant and take $Q$ to be the identity endofunctor, then what you want is true. The problem with your condition is that it involves an object that is not necessarily cofibrant, so it is impossible to say what the derived functor does to it.

Comment: You're simply talking about those homotopy colimits such that the canonical map to the honest colimit admits a section up to homotopy. I don't think one can answer your questions unless you impose conditions on the preservation of colimits by Q.